# ObservableCollection with [ObservableProperty] attribute does not trigger NotifyCanExecuteChanged when items added or removed from collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm having some issues using an ObservableCollection and `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` whereby when the collection is changed (i.e. items added or removed) `MyCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged` is not called.

I have a collection like this:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(MyCommand))]
private ObservableCollection<Foo> selectedItems = new();
```

The binding in the view looks like this: `{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=TwoWay}`

The generated code from `ObservableProperty]` looks like this:

```cs
/// <inheritdoc cref="selectedItems"/>
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.ObservablePropertyGenerator", "8.2.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public global::System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<global::Foo> SelectedItems
{
    get => selectedItems;
    [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.MemberNotNull("selectedItems")]
    set
    {
        if (!global::System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<global::System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<global::Foo>>.Default.Equals(selectedItems, value))
        {
            OnSelectedItemsChanging(value);
            OnSelectedItemsChanging(default, value);
            OnPropertyChanging(global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.__Internals.__KnownINotifyPropertyChangingArgs.SelectedItems);
            selectedItems = value;
            OnSelectedItemsChanged(value);
            OnSelectedItemsChanged(default, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.__Internals.__KnownINotifyPropertyChangedArgs.SelectedItems);
            MyCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I can fix this by manually subscribing to the `CollectionChanged` event in the ViewModel and triggering it:

```cs
this.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += this.SelectedItemsCollectionChangedHandler;

...

public void SelectedItemsCollectionChangedHandler(object? value, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add ||
        args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        this.MyCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

However, that seems to defeat the point of having `ObservableProperty` on an `ObservableCollection`... Am I fundementally misunderstanding what `ObservablyProperty` is meant to do when used on a collection? Is there a way to avoid the boilerplate of having to manually subscribe and handle `CollectionChanged` in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the generated code for your property (last line in set), `MyCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged` is called only when SelectedItems is set (when you do `SelectedItems = ...`), not when its content changes (adding or removing items for example).

Afaik NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor won't work for your case and I know no other solution than doing more or less what you already did, handling CollectionChanged manually.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know I'm not completely missing a trick at least.

Comment: It is not a trick but a basic understanding: `INotifyPropertyChanged` should notify when the property value has changed. The property value in this case is the reference to a collection and that reference has not changed.